# Query to perform a complex Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a fact Shipping table in SQL server with Country and Qty fields. Something like this:

| Contry | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| BR | 5,789 |
| MX | 3,654 |
| CO | 1,587 |
| BR | 3,989 |
| AR | 654 |

I want to perform a GROUP BY region, but there are countries that are in multiple regions at same time.
For example, Brazil is in the region Brazil and LATAM at the same time. Colombia is in the region Colombia, MCLA and LATAM at the same time.
How can I write a query to have a output like this:

| Region | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| LATAM | 22,574 |
| Brazil | 13,878 |
| MCLA | 8,696 |
| Colombia | 4,355 |

Where LATAM region is basically the total Qty, Brazil region is just the Qty of Brazil, MCLA region is the QTY of LATAM minus Brazil and Colombia region is just the Qty of Colombia

I don't even know where to start...

Comment: Where is the region info stored? You don't show where that should come from.

Comment: you need a table that defines which county belongs to which region, join that and group by region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's helpful when you post a question like this to include your example data as reproducible DDL/DML. I prefer table variables for this, but that's just personal preference. Consider:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (Country VARCHAR(2), Qty INT);
INSERT INTO @Table (Country, Qty) VALUES
('BR', 5789), ('MX', 3654), ('CO', 1587),
('BR', 3989), ('AR', 654 );

DECLARE @Regions TABLE (Country VARCHAR(2), Region VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @Regions (Country, Region) VALUES
('BR','Brazil'), ('BR', 'LATAM'),
('MX','MCLA'), ('MX', 'LATAM'),
('CO','Columbia'),('CO','MCLA'), ('CO', 'LATAM'),
('AR', 'LATAM'),('AR','MCLA');
```

Using this, with the defined relationships between a country code and a region we can group by the region column:

```
SELECT r.Region, SUM(Qty) AS Qty
  FROM @table t
    INNER JOIN @Regions r
      ON t.Country = r.Country
 GROUP BY r.Region
```

The relationships defined in the regions table can have as many country codes for a single region as you'd like. Based on your question I added every country code to LATAM, and all but BR to MCLA, so so on.